# 'statechange' not firing after pushState

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, history.js

I'm using;

```
history.js
history.adapter.jquery.js
jquery-1.11.0.min.js
internet explorer 11.0.9600.16476
```

History bookmarking is working fine for Chrome and Firefox. When I use ie in the config above the 'statechage' event doesn't fire after a call to `pushState()`. Also, using Visual Studio 2012, the output windows reports;

Exception was thrown at line 2, column 10683 in //localhost:3000/Js/Master/0_jquery-1.11.0.min.js?ver=1.0 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved my issue. As I was setting `History.options.html4Mode = true`, I needed to include the `history.html4.js`.